# Tensorflow JS universal sentence encoder in webworker

Tags: web-worker, tensorflow.js

I am running USE in webworker and it is running fine.
I am trying to pass model to webworker. The reason behind this is that each time a webworker runs it downloads a new model. While passing model in post message following error is displayed:

```
Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'Worker': function t(t,n){return e.apply(this,arguments)} could not be cloned.
```

Tried to serialize the model and pass it but model has circular dependency so it cannot be serialized.

Is there any alternate method to pass model to web worker?

The goal behind passing model is to improve the execution time of the embed function of the USE

Answer (score 0):

A model cannot be passed between workers because a model object cannot be serialized and only serialized object are allowed as messages according to the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers).

Models need not to be pass between workers instances. The model output and input can however being exchanged between the workers

Comment: The worker is downloading the model each time it runs. So if there are 10 workers running then 10 instances of model will be downloaded which I want to avoid. Hence I was trying to pass the model in postmessage

Comment: As I said it is not possible to share the model between the workers. Why don't you want to download the model 10 times if you have 10 workers and instead want to share it 10 times accross the workers ?

Comment: I dont want to download the model to save the download time and bandwidth